# Change class member once it is loaded in puppet

Tags: manifest, puppet

Here's the scenario: I'm using the same 3rd party parameterized class in 2 different places in my manifests.

I don't know where the 3rd party class will be included first and in both places, I need to pass a different parameter to the class.

Right now, I only `include` the class in both places since I don't know how to resolve my situation.

Any help appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only declare a class once when you are using the syntax with Parameters.

```
include classname
```

can be used multiple times, but

```
class { 'classname':
   parameter => 'yada',
}
```

only once.